# Why is Ka of weak acid increasing while being diluted?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am calculating $K_\mathrm{a}$ and percent dissociation of acetic acid being diluted to $\pu{1.00 \times 10^{-1} M}$, $\pu{1.00 \times 10^{-2} M}$, and $\pu{1.00 \times 10^{-4} M}$.

The $\mathrm{pH}$ goes up as the weak acid is diluted, which is to be expected.
The % dissociation is inversely related to the initial concentration of acetic acid.

However, I fail to understand why the $K_\mathrm{a}$ value increases (slightly) as the solution gets more dilute. Isn't $K_\mathrm{a}$ supposed to be a **constant** (acid dissociation constant) therefore stay constant as long as the temperature stays constant? Isn't according to Le Chatelier's principle, $K_\mathrm{a}$ is a function of temperature?

Comment: The simplest solution is that your calculation is wrong or not accurate enough. As you say, it's a constant.

Comment: The scale at which you are working, the standard formulas won't work. You will have to solve a quadratic equation to get the results. The standard formulas are just an approximation to make our lives easy.

Comment: Have you involved ion activity coefficients ? How *exactly* have you calculated Ka ? Have you applied any implicit or explict simplifying assumptions ?

Comment: E.g. the famous formula pH=0.5(pKa - log c) assumes c >> [H+] >> [OH-].

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include the readings you got during the experiment. That might help us understand where the problem is, approximations or just experimental error.

Comment: $K_a ≠ x^2/0.100$, rather $K_a ≈ x^2/0.100$. This expression assumes the condition mentioned by @Poutnik. Divide by $0.100-x$ instead. Even after that the results might me screwed because when $x<10^{-6}$,  even self ionization of water causes significant change in $\mathrm{pH}$.

Comment: You should rather involve in the question the used algebraic equations explicitly.   A claim not making assumptions may be an assumption itself, not necesserily correct. By other words, if you do not say what you did, we cannot say what you did wrong.

Comment: Try to make it complete. And be aware of x^2/(c-x)  not x^2/c-x .Consider also Activity coefficients. Another case is oH meter calibration. How did you do it for low pH values ?

Comment: Remember that with increasing [ionic strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_strength), [activity coeefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_coefficient) decrease, according to [Debye-Hueckel equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye%E2%80%93H%C3%BCckel_equation). So while activity based Ka is constant, concentration based Ka grows with the acid and therefore ion concentration.